# Can I get pytesseract command to work properly in pycharm which is throwing errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, tesseract

I am defining a fucntion which is converting an image to grayscale (bit black white) after that I am passing it to:

```
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(gray_scale_image))
```

and then I am print the text what I am receiving but it is throwing errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\nayaproject\venv\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2613, in open
fp.seek(0)
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'seek'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/HP/PycharmProjects/nayaproject/new.py", line 17, in <module>
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(g))
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\nayaproject\venv\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2615, in open
fp = io.BytesIO(fp.read())
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'read'
```

And instead of Image.open(grayscale), when I use Image.fromarray(grayscale) i got these errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\nayaproject\venv\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 170, in run_tesseract
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd_args, **subprocess_args())
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 997, in _execute_child
startupinfo)

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/HP/PycharmProjects/nayaproject/new.py", line 17, in <module>
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.fromarray(g))
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\nayaproject\venv\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 294, in image_to_string
return run_and_get_output(*args)
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\nayaproject\venv\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 202, in run_and_get_output
run_tesseract(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\nayaproject\venv\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 172, in run_tesseract
raise TesseractNotFoundError()
pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractNotFoundError: tesseract is not installed or it's not in your path
```

I am working on PyCharm, and I've already installed Pillow, numpy, opencv-python, pip and pytesseract for this project.

Comment: how did you install tesseract?

Comment: Image.open(gray_scale_image) =>  What are you passing here as gray_scale_image ? This should be full path to the image ie a string and not an image object (not array)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since I guess **gray_scale_image** is output from OpenCV and is therefore numpy array as error suggests

`AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'read'`

you need to transform array to PIL object. From my own experience, I suggest you to automaticly transform numpy array to np.uint8, because PIL works with 8bit and you usually dont have overview of what gets out of OpenCV algorithms.

```
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.fromarray(gray_scale_image.astype(np.uint8)))
```

If the above mentioned doesnt work, you definitly dont pass Image array of any form. Try to type these to find character of arguemnt:

```
print(type(gray_scale_image))
print(gray_scale_image.shape)
```

After this will solve your first problem, new one will occur of which you do not know yet. You need to add path to your pytesseract

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractNotFoundError: tesseract is not installed or it's not in your path
```

Solution is to add your path at the beginning

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract'
TESSDATA_PREFIX = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Tesseract-OCR'
```

Comment: Thanks man it does work perfectly, but the tesseract not giving the right outcomes from the id card that i've provided to it, any help on this matter?

Comment: Sure. I was working recenly on license plate recognition.These points are very important:1) Tesseract works in such a way, that translates a real text - by that I mean a text generated by font. Its build for pdfs and so on. So install font of your id card into your tesseract - this will save you days of research ->(http://trainyourtesseract.com/) 2) Increase resolution of input array(simply resize array with opencv or PIL).3) Super important - Image you are processing must be totally clean. No extra dots or so on.In paiting,write some text, save as png, load it and try to translate - must work

Comment: 4) the image you want to run through tesseract should be thresholded (only [0,0,0] for background and [255,255,255] for text). When I was doing License plate recognition I had to run pytesseract.image_to_string() for same image with different thresholds values to get some output for sure.  If you are not getting any output, its ok, just try image with purly generated text from Painting and it should work. Something like this: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/1ns8tGgdpLY/maxresdefault.jpg

Comment: If you want to see how to train and integrate new font into your pytesseract(adding font will increase the recognition superbly), create new question and give here link, will answer it tommorow - its not hard, but tricky, because a lot of tutorials doesnt work and It requires little more explanation - this comment window is not really good for it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53761979/how-can-i-train-my-python-based-ocr-with-tesseract-to-train-with-different-natio Here is the question for Tesseract to train with ID cards